# I would like "mouse click listener" to create a marker on a photo in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I am looking at marking an image with circle an cross and the program would be counting the cross and circle.

Example : right Click  -> cross and left click ->circle

I also wish to be able to click again on the circle or the cross to make it disappear.

So what I wish is to not use a button. Example of what I want to achieve: i have a photo with a lot of cats and dogs: I want the number of animal in the image so if I click right on the image on a cat I will see a cross appear and if I click left on a dog I will see a circle. visually I can see if I clicked on each animal and the program can count the number of click right and click left to tell me how many dog and how many cats I have in the picture.

Do any of you could help me to put me in the right direction to do that? If it is possible.

Comment: Don't add further details in answers. That's not what they are for! Instead [edit] the question to add more info. I've done that here, and flagged the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is check if the button has been enabled or not. If it has been clicked, then you can set the image that was added onto the picture, to the original picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

First, create a GUI model class to hold the image and a `List` of markers.  Create a `Marker` class to hold a `boolean` and a `java.awt.Point`.  The boolean determines whether to draw a cross or a naught.  The `Point` determines where to draw the cross or naught.

You'll have to determine how close to an existing marker `Point` counts as a deletion, rather than an addition.

Second, create a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel` to hold the image.  You can look at the Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see how to create a drawing `JPanel`.

Third, create a control `JPanel` to display the number of crosses and naughts in the GUI model `List`.

Fourth, create a `MouseAdapter` to listen for mouse clicks, and add or remove a marker for the GUI model `List`, depending on whether the marker exists or not.

Here's what the GUI might look like.

[image: GUI]

Comment: Yeah exactly thanks a lot! I really appreciate it !